# How to show the current #pragma pack setting in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Here is an example how to set the current #pragma pack:

```
#pragma pack(4)
```

How is it possible to show the current #pragma pack setting?

Comment: This is not a C++ thing; it is a compiler thing. State your compiler name and version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Microsoft's C++ compiler you can use

```
#pragma pack(show)
```

which causes the compiler to [issue a warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack) containing the value.

Note this is not standard C++ (and neither is any guise of `#pragma pack`) so other compilers may or may not have this feature. At the time of writing GCC, for example, doesn't.

Comment: Note that `#pragma pack` is entirely non-standard; Not just `#pragma pack(show)`.

Answer (score 2):

For Microsoft Visual C++ use

```
#pragma pack(show)
```

It will generate the following compiler warning:

```
Warning C4810   value of pragma pack(show) == 4
```